# Text label that explains what a certain button in the app would do

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a text label component that will act as an in-app tutorial explanatory label in Flutter. This text label should show up above a button explaining the clicking on that button would result in creating a new entry.

[image]

I tried using a Tooltip widget to wrap the button. But tooltip shows up only when long pressed the button. I need this widget to be visible if the user doesn't already have any entries created.

Comment: one can use this link: https://pub.dev/packages/super_tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I thought of giving you this short but small help about this. I just want you to see whether it is helping you in any way or not.

My idea is to trigger the `tooltip` programatically. Let me know tell you how to do that, although there is no available documentation to do that. I did some research too on this.

> 1. Use `ensureTooltipVisible` from `_TooltipState` using a `GlobalKey` to fetch it.
> 2. Typically you'd do the following field inside the widget instantiating `Tooltip : final key = new GlobalKey();`

Then in your tooltip you will assign this key

```
final _key = new GlobalKey()

ToolTip(
  key: _key
)
```

And in the `initState()` you just check whether there are some entries or not:

```
initState(){
  super.initState();
  if(_yourData == null){
    //that's how you trigger it
    final dynamic tooltip = _key.currentState;
    tooltip.ensureTooltipVisible();
  }
}
```

`initState()` is the method which gets initialized when you open up your page every time. So as soon as you will open up your page, the info will be checked and hence it will show accordingly. Let me know if that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can make using `OverlayEntry`.

Here is sample code

```dart
final overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
  builder: (BuildContext context) => Positioned(
    top: _yourCustomTop,
    left: _yourCustomLeft,
    child: FadeTransition(
      opacity: CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _yourController,
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      ),
      child: Material(
        color: const Color(0x00ffffff),
        child: Container(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            shape: TooltipShapeBorder(radius: 6, arrowArc: 0.2),
            shadows: [
              const BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black26,
                blurRadius: 4.0,
                offset: const Offset(2, 2),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 84,
            height: 44,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('_yourString'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    ),
  ),
);
Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry);
```

## TooltipShapeBorder

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58352984/14434806).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TooltipShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final double arrowWidth;
  final double arrowHeight;
  final double arrowArc;
  final double radius;

  TooltipShapeBorder({
    this.radius = 16.0,
    this.arrowWidth = 20.0,
    this.arrowHeight = 10.0,
    this.arrowArc = 0.0,
  }) : assert(arrowArc <= 1.0 && arrowArc >= 0.0);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.only(bottom: arrowHeight);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    rect = Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, arrowHeight));
    double x = arrowWidth, y = arrowHeight, r = 1 - arrowArc;
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(radius)))
      ..moveTo(rect.bottomCenter.dx + x / 2, rect.bottomCenter.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, y * r)
      ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(-x / 2 * (1 - r), y * (1 - r), -x * (1 - r), 0)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, -y * r);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can already show a label quite easily like this:

```
const Tooltip(
      message: 'Hi there!',
      triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap, // ensures the label appears when tapped
      preferBelow: false, // use this if you want the label above the widget
      child: Icon(Icons.interests),
    )
```

You can use `triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.manual` for further customization ;)

Or you could use the [showcaseview](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview) package

You can find more info for the Tooltip widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html)