# Flutter design Instagram like balloons / tooltip widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in flutter i would like to design this layout as widget

[image]

and current implemented code has this result:

[image]

could you help me to fix some problem on this desing?

in that height/weight and corners should be customizable and i should can put some widget into that, for example:

[image]

```
class MessageClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  MessageClipper({this.borderRadius = 15});
  final double borderRadius;
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    double width = size.width;
    double height = size.height;
    double rheight = height - height / 3;
    double oneThird = width / 3;

    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, rheight - borderRadius)
      ..cubicTo(0, rheight - borderRadius, 0, rheight, borderRadius, rheight)
      ..lineTo(oneThird, rheight)
      ..lineTo(width/2-borderRadius, height-borderRadius)
      ..cubicTo(width / 2 - borderRadius, height - borderRadius, width / 2,
          height, width / 2 + borderRadius, height - borderRadius )
      ..lineTo(2 * oneThird, rheight)
      ..lineTo(width-borderRadius, rheight)
      ..cubicTo(width - borderRadius, rheight, width, rheight, width,
          rheight - borderRadius)
      ..lineTo(width, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Comment: @kherel could you help me on this post? thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830 , it makes balloons like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDXMA.png - but its up to you how you customize it

Comment: so did you see the above answer? did you see how you can do it in an easy way and also make it "clickable"? what is the reason to use such complicated code as below answer?

Comment: @pskink below answer is not complicate as i think, and that easy to use in less code

Comment: yes it is, it is a workaround as the author was not able to make a balloon like shape and combined it by using a standard decoration and a custom paint - instead it should be done by defining a custom shape (`ShapeBorder`) or by defing a custom clip (`CustomClipper`) - if you want to use such workarounds its up to you though...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Edit:** As pskink metioned in this question: [Flutter - ClipPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942533/flutter-clippath/57943257#57943257), this would be the correct way to achieve what you want:

```
class TooltipShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final double arrowWidth;
  final double arrowHeight;
  final double arrowArc;
  final double radius;

  TooltipShapeBorder({
    this.radius = 16.0,
    this.arrowWidth = 20.0,
    this.arrowHeight = 10.0,
    this.arrowArc = 0.0,
  }) : assert(arrowArc <= 1.0 && arrowArc >= 0.0);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.only(bottom: arrowHeight);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => null;

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    rect = Rect.fromPoints(rect.topLeft, rect.bottomRight - Offset(0, arrowHeight));
    double x = arrowWidth, y = arrowHeight, r = 1 - arrowArc;
    return Path()
      ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, Radius.circular(radius)))
      ..moveTo(rect.bottomCenter.dx + x / 2, rect.bottomCenter.dy)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, y * r)
      ..relativeQuadraticBezierTo(-x / 2 * (1 - r), y * (1 - r), -x * (1 - r), 0)
      ..relativeLineTo(-x / 2 * r, -y * r);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
}
```

This is how to use it:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Instagram Like Balloon Tooltip'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: ShapeDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          shape: TooltipShapeBorder(arrowArc: 0.5),
          shadows: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black26, blurRadius: 4.0, offset: Offset(2, 2))
          ],
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text('Text 22', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

And this would be the result:

[image: Instagram Like Balloon Tooltip in Flutter]

If you want to change the curvature of the arrow, you can use the `arrowArc` propery of the `TooltipShapeBorder`, if you set it to `0.0` it won't have any curvature and if you set it to `1.0` it will have the maximum curvature.

To see how `quadraticBezierTo` works and how to make other shapes check this link: [Paths in Flutter: A Visual Guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0)

Comment: thanks, so much, how about triangle corners? how can i set radius for them?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943257/2252830 on how to create a custom shapes like "message balloons" - it is done by extending `ShapeBorder` class

Comment: this is from `ShapeBorder` official documentation: *"Subclasses define various shapes, like circles (CircleBorder), rounded rectangles (RoundedRectangleBorder), continuous rectangles (ContinuousRectangleBorder), or beveled rectangles (BeveledRectangleBorder)."*

Comment: btw you can also use your `TooltipShapeBorder` as a "clickable balloon" - see the `ButtonMessage` widget from the link i posted - it uses `Material` and `InkWell` widgets internally

Comment: how to move arrow to left ?