# Enable Button on flutter only if Checkbox is " checked"

Tags: flutter

Hello guys I have registration form with checkbox to be enabled in order to allow registration.
I need my user to do checkbox checked to have button enabled otherwise an tooltip will be shown.. like... " u need to accept terms and condition to register... "
This is the part of the CheckBox:

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white,),
                      child: Checkbox(
                        focusColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                        activeColor: Colors.orange,
                        value: rememberMe,
                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            rememberMe = (newValue);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(children: [
                        TextSpan(
                          text: 'Accetto le condizioni e ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                        TextSpan(
                          text: 'il trattamento dei dati personali ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10,decoration: TextDecoration.underline,),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
```

and this the "registration Button"

```
ButtonTheme(
                  minWidth: 100,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                    elevation: 10,
                    onPressed: () async {

                      setState(() {
                        showSpinner = true;
                      });
                      try {
                        final newUser =
                            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: email, password: password);
                        if (newUser != null) {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                          );
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          showSpinner = false;
                        });
                      } catch (e) {
                        print(e);
                      }
                    },
                    color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                    child: Text(
                      'SIGNUP',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain things which I would like to give you an insight about. Which will help you surely, so follow along.

**Pointers**

- Read upon [Flutter Form and it's Validation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation), which answers your question on showing up the error message under your forms for the validations
- One very useful widget to achieve what you want is [Flutter Tooltip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html) **Unfortunately, you cannot bring up the tooltip which you wanted to do programmatically**

**Workaround:** Do use any of these to show up you message

- [Snackbar Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/snackbars)
- [Flutter AlerDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html)
- Simply show up a text, like a validator for the form under the checkbox like I will demonstrate in the code for you

Now, I have demonstrated both of them in this code, but the code is not similar. It would be enough to you let you know the best practices you can do along with your tooltip message showcase

**Please note:** To make a tooltip like structure using `Container()`, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58352984/5362583) answer, will help you in a great extent

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool rememberMe = false;
  
  // this bool will check rememberMe is checked
  bool showErrorMessage = false;
  
  //for form Validation
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  // retiurning the validator message here
                  return value.isEmpty ? "Please enter the message" : null;
                }
              )
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Accept Terms & Conditions'),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0),
                Checkbox(
                  focusColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                  activeColor: Colors.orange,
                  value: rememberMe,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() => rememberMe = newValue);
                  }
                )
              ]
            ),
            // based up on this bool value
            showErrorMessage ? 
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text('Please accept the terms and conditions to proceed...')
              )
            )
            : Container(),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Submit'),
              onPressed: (){
                // for your form validation
                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                  // do your success operation here!
                  // checking for the rememberValue
                  // and setting the message bool data
                  if(rememberMe != true)
                    setState(() => showErrorMessage = true);
                  else
                    setState(() => showErrorMessage = false);
                }
              }
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**How it works?**

It will first check whether the form is empty, if it not, then checks whether the checkbox is empty or not

**Fun Fact**

You can use the above logic or `bool showErrorMessage`, to show anything, be it, `SnackBar`, `AlertDialog` or the message which I showed in the above code.

**Result**

[image: Result GIF]

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `null` to the `onPressed` of a `Button` to make it disabled. So you'll need to pass `null` to the `onPressed` of the `RaisedButton` when `rememberMe` is `false`.

```dart
ButtonTheme(
    minWidth: 100,
    height: 50.0,
    child: RaisedButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      elevation: 10,
      onPressed: rememberMe ? () async {

        setState(() {
          showSpinner = true;
        });
        try {
          final newUser =
          await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email, password: password);
          if (newUser != null) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
            );
          }
          setState(() {
            showSpinner = false;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      } : null, // make it null if false
      color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
      child: Text(
        'SIGNUP',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: thanks! and how to add a tooltip text when they click on the button and see that doesnt work...

Comment: The color of the button should indicate that it's disabled

Comment: One other thing you can do is to not disable the button but show a snackbar or toast saying they need to check the checkbox when they tap the button